# Trigger action in LUIS using same entity more than once

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, azure-language-understanding

I want to trigger an action for an intent once 2 types of Cereal have been requested but it seems an action can only have one parameter instance of a given type?

[image]

[image]

Am I misunderstanding the purpose of actions?